# How to add composer to winginx?

Tags: configuration, composer-php, localhost, winginx

How to add composer to winginx on windows 10? when i try to load install for composer from winginx php71 folder it does throw an error PHP Warning:  Module 'zip' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

I did tried to install composer being in php71 folder, but it fails with above error, and i can't edit zip.dll

```
php -r "eval('?>'.file_get_contents('https://getcomposer.org/installer'));"

c:\Winginx\php71>php -r "eval('?>'.file_get_contents('https://getcomposer.org/installer'));"

Warning: Module 'zip' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Warning: file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in Command line code on line 1

Warning: file_get_contents(https://getcomposer.org/installer): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Command line code on line 1
```

Comment: I'm also having the same question...

Comment: I just found the answer

Answer (score 0):

go to directory for php71
open php.ini
look for extension=php_zip.dll and change it into

```
;extension=php_zip.dll
```